# Solr schemantic search on a single field

Tags: solr, semantics

I'm working on real estate website, we store the locations (geo coordinates) of properties in a  table and property attributes like bedroom, bathroom etc in other table.

Now I have to implement a text based search for the properties in which user can enter free text (eg. 3 bedroom apartment in sector 30 gurgaon).

OK so here is my approach im following, i am trying to use solr to parse the the text entered by user and get the meaning full keywords out of it so that I can query my db to get the results.
so far I have created some fields in `schema.xml`

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="type" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

and indexed some sample data like:

```
{
        "id": "4",
        "text": "park centra",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432256308412400
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "text": "park avenue",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432273214603300
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "text": "swimming pool",
        "type": "amenity",
        "_version_": 1466432327754186800
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "sector 30",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432234501177300
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "text": "City park",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432303613870000
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "Gurgaon",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432219763441700
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "text": "bedroom",
        "type": "bedroom",
        "_version_": 1466432362205151200
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "text": "bhk",
        "type": "bedroom",
        "_version_": 1466432369752801300
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "text": "ATM",
        "type": "amenity",
        "_version_": 1466432341620555800
      }
```

Now what I want solr to do for me is that when a user enters a text like "2 bedroom in sector 30". The solr should search for the words in `text` field, Group by `type` and pick the most relevant result from every group. so that i can get results like

```
{
        "id": "9",
        "text": "bedroom",
        "type": "bedroom",
        "_version_": 1466432362205151200
      },
 {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "sector 30",
        "type": "location",
        "_version_": 1466432234501177300
      }
```

Now I can easily make a query on the db and get the results.

Can you tell me how achieve this kind of behaviour from solr, and also if this is possible or not?

Comment: Here is how I would do it, for the # of bedrooms and options like that instead of Text field I would have put a check box and for location a separate text box, so you wont need to pars the search String and figure and extract entities. it seems you are looking for. A Faceted search in combination with few text field is what you will probably need .

Comment: Thanks for reply, if im getting you right i have to create a field for each of the attribute, i can take forward that approach but i want to implement a semantic search.

Comment: what do you mean by "Semantic Search" that is a loaded word! From what I understood from your question, if we look it high level. You have bunch of properties, these properties have some characteristics such as # of bedrooms or Type of property (town house or condo , etc) For those characteristics that are usually fixed or with in a specific range you can design your application such that you perform a faceted search. For example if your user checks 3 bedroom checkbox then solr will filter out everything else that is not 3 bedroom property.

Comment: For other characteristic such as location you can have a Text box and send that as part of the query to solr. You have even have the location field indexed in your data so when the user starts typing solr can even give the user suggestions based on the index field.

Comment: i know i can do that, if i provide user a dropdown or checkbox. but in my case its just a textfield where user can write free text, eg: "3 bedroom apartment in sector 30 gurgaon"  please read my question properly, i have mentioned my scenario.

Comment: I wasn't talking about drop down for the suggestion by the way, I was talking about solr providing suggestion based on the indexed text in your data.

Comment: For what you want to do I can think of two options: 
1. You can parse the user string and extract entities, construct a query for solr based on what you extracted and send it to solr. 
2. Merge all the fields as a text field in your data & have solr index them so when user types solr will search the data set based on the user string. (probably not a good idea).You will have to introduce some structured way for user to query so you can extract entities. For instance (# of bedrooms, City) that way you can parse the user input for what you want.